# set up development environment windows

Tags: local-installation

I have a live website (hosted by GoDaddy). I would like to set up a development environment on my local computer (Windows 8) so that I can make changes and see how things look, and then push them over to the live site. What's the best way to do that?

I saw some similar questions, but none of them said how to get my live website set up on my local computer.

Thanks!

Comment: This is [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for WPSE.  Your best bet is probably Google.  Searching for [`setup wordpress development windows 8`](https://www.google.com/search?q=setup+wordpress+development+windows+8) is one possible starting point.  (One promising hit: [How to Install WordPress using WAMP](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/).)

Comment: Chat, or the WP Forums may be better for this, questions need to be answerable, and this is a tad subjective, lots of answers that are neither right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install Xampp or Wamp on your computer first. Then setup a Virtual Host on your computer which will make sure your when you type your website address, it will point it to the local installation of your computer.

Download XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html
Setting up Virtual Host: http://ddmboss.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-xampp/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm now following the steps to set up Virtual Host, and I'm stuck on #7. I can't find this line in my hosts file:    127.0.0.1             localhost. My hosts file is completely commented out.

Comment: That's fine, add yours under all the commented section and you'll be fine.

Comment: Why are there so many lines? (127.0.0.1             localhost
127.0.0.1             www.somesite.dev
127.0.0.1             www.multisite.dev
127.0.0.1             demo.multisite.dev
127.0.0.1             www.testsite.dev #change this to the domain name you chose earlier).                                      Do I need to use all of them?

Comment: Don't add all of them. Just add `127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com`

Comment: I added mywebsite.dev, like the instructions said, and now Apache won't start!

Comment: Can you copy and paste what you inserted in the vhosts.conf

Comment: 127.0.0.1             www.goinspire.dev                                (my website is goinspire.com)

Comment: That's the content from the hosts file, I want the vhosts.conf

Comment: Oops - here: http://pastebin.com/5NtSQfz0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10871/discussion-between-user3515-and-isuthan-bala)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I found it was easier to set up Desktop Server than XAMPP:

http://serverpress.com/products/desktopserver/

Comment: Thanks! I already have XAMPP installed, so unless it gives me problems I think I'll stick with it.